# Recursive definition of products

Tags: abstract-algebra, recursion, magma

Let $(M,*)$ be a Magma. How can one recursively define products such as $(a_1*a_2)*(a_3*(a_4*a_5))$ and so on ?
The basic idea is i think that we have something like : $P^1(a_1)=a_1$ and $P^n(a_1,....,a_n)=P^k(a_1,..a_k)*P^l(a_{k+1},..,a_n)$, with $k+l=n$.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this is an answer, but perhaps it can help you develop your own answer. The following paper of Bjorn Poonen is short and has a section on products which may be of interest: https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.0135

Comment: Notice that "definition" is ambiguous, since, in general, $*$ is not associative. So $$P^n(a_1,\ldots,a_n)*P^m(a_{n+1},\ldots,a_{n+m})\neq P^j(a_1,\ldots,a_j)*P^{n+m-j}(a_{j+1},\ldots,a_{n+m})$$ if $1\leq j\leq n+m$